# Is output pin set to LOW grounded

Tags: arduino-mega, c

If I do following:

```
pinMode(MYPIN, OUTPUT)
digitalWrite(MYPIN, LOW)
```

What will happen? Will this effectively ground *MYPIN* or output some low voltage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will effectively connect the pin to ground. Note that the connection is
made by a transistor that has a finite resistance. This output resistance is
not really specified, but from the curves on the “typical characteristics”
section of the datasheet you can infer that the *typical* value is about
26 Ω.

The only hard specification states that the `OUTPUT` `LOW` voltage
should be no larger than 0.9 V, as long as the pin is not sinking
more than 20 mA. C.f. the table “DC characteristics” of the
[ATmega2560
datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2549-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf#page=355).